# I got a stuck with .htaccess and rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I'm using Lamp server on linuxmint and i installed 2 wordpress platforms on it one called "bfsite" and the other one called "titus". I modified the .htacces file as WordPress suggest me to do

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bfsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bfsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This one is for bfsite, and the I modify for the /titus platform

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /titus/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /titus/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And a simple redirect.

```
Redirect /index.php http://89.39.166.81/titus
```

As you see I made my locahost online for you to see what's happening, when I try to go on

```
http://89.39.166.81/titus/about
```

It returns to me with `http://localhost/titus/dev/` and also if you force to with this path

```
http://89.39.166.81/titus/dev/
```

It comes with a 404 and page not found error, but is going with the "bfsite" wordpress platform.

Answer (score 0):

since you are under a ubuntu distro you can use this

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

-- then you can enable postname from wp backend. good luck!

Comment: Module rewrite already enabled --> this is what my terminal respond to me, i think the code i entered in the  .htaccess is making the conflict Regards !

Comment: oh yeah, delete everything u have in .htaccess go in bfsite folder via the terminal sudo gedit .htaccess and paste this. for titus folder replace in the code below "bfsite"  with "titus" and repeate the process!
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bfsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bfsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Is wotking ! Thank you Ciprian